# Error code 91 - Object variable or with Block variable not set - OOP, class method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with VBA classes, could you please have a look at the following code? It crushes at the `Set GetCustIdBeginningMap = Mapping.GetCustomerIdBeginningMap`

```
   Private Function GetCustIdBeginningMap() As Scripting.Dictionary '<String, Currency>
   Dim Output As New Scripting.Dictionary
   Dim Mapping As WorksheetBeginningValueSource
   'Output.Add "1212990404", 101000000
   Set GetCustIdBeginningMap = Mapping.GetCustomerIdBeginningMap
   End Function
```

the class:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const ClassName As String = "WorksheetBeginningValueSource"
Public Function GetCustomerIdBeginningMap() As Scripting.Dictionary
  Const MethodName = "GetCustomerIdBeginningMap"
'extracting data from Excel
```

Comment: The error is because you have not created Mapping yet.  Before you can use it, you need to `New` it.

Comment: Thank you, Brian! I still cannot get used to VBA